# Sync failed unable to resolve dependency

Tags: gradle

i've just downloaded Android Studio yesterday and when it start building the project i got this error `Gradle Sync Failed` and the following error messages : [image]

If someone can help me please, i've tried the 'offline work' trick but it was already unchecked.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: If you just downloaded the IDE and you've newer worked before, you need to download your dependencies at the beginning, then you can work offline. Can you give more details?

Comment: I dont mind work offline or online, thing is that when i launch the project it goes ' UNable to resolve dependency for ...' for many things.
Where can i download these dependencies ? because i can't get the design editor (gradle project sync failed). I'm new to this, sorry if i'm not very accurate about the problem.

Comment: Try narrowing down the problem. Close the IDE and try to build the project from the command line (using Gradle). Solve the issues with Gradle build (if any) and try syncing again.